# Hiding .html file extension from site url

Tags: nginx, file-extension

I've tried this:http://www.tweaktalk.net/60/nginx-remove-php-file-extension-from-url but it didn't quite work for me. I'm getting either Error 404 or Error 505

I'm using Digital Ocean hosting with nginx server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone wants to know how I solved this:

I've went to the directory */etc/nginx/conf.d* , created there a folder called *'domain.trade.conf'*, for example if my domain is *example.com*, the folder name would be *example.com.conf*.

In this file I've added this code:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  example.com; #Domain
    root         /var/www/html; #The place of your site files
    access_log   /var/www/html/logs/access.log; #Where to log the accesses
    error_log    /var/www/html/logs/error.log; #Where to log the errors

    location / { 
        try_files $uri $uri/ @htmlext;
    }   

    location ~ \.html$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }   

    location @htmlext {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ $1.html last;
    } 
}
```

Hope I helped you.